# Kotlin IndexOutOfBoundsException on list to map convertion

Tags: java, android, list, kotlin, collections

Iam trying to convert a Dynamic string to map using kotlin `associate()` transformation and its working properly

Since my query string is Dynamic, sometimes it might not contain required data and thus throwing IndexOutOfBoundsException

```
fun convetToMap(val data: String) : Map<String, String> {
    return data.split(",").associate { str ->
           str.split("=").let { 
              (key, value) -> key to value
           }
    }
}
```

val string1 = "id1=1,id2=2,id3=3,id4=4,id5=5"
val string2 = "id1=1,id2=2,id3=3,id4=4,id"

`convetToMap(string1)` runs perfectly and results `{id1=1, id2=2, id3=3, id4=4, id5=5}`

when i'm trying to run `convetToMap(string2)` it throws IOB Exception and the logcat says

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 1, Size: 1
 at java.util.Collections$SingletonList.get (Collections.java:4815)
```

is there a way to resolve this by using assocaite(), i have tried using conditions but that couldn't help to solve

Comment: The second input is invalid, it causes `split("=")` to result in an array of a single element and that leads to the exception. You would have to either provide a default value or check if the input is well-formed before you use it in this `fun`. By the way, `data` is a Kotlin keyword I wouldn't use as an argument name...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could `filter` before associating, if you just want to eliminate the bad inputs:

```
fun convetToMap(val data: String) : Map<String, String> =
    data.split(",")
        .filter { it.contains("=") }
        .associate { str ->
           str.split("=").let { 
              (key, value) -> key to value
           }
```